# how to control latLngBounds.southwest and latLngBounds.northeast is coming outside the polygon?

Tags: android, google-maps, gis, polygon

I have found center point, northeast and southwest coordinates using latlongbounds but northeast and southwest coordinates are coming outside the polygon, how to control that

```
     LatLngBounds latLngBounds = getPolygonCenterPoint(mMap, mLatLngCollection);

 mPolylineOptions.color(Color.GREEN);
 mPolylineOptions.add(latLngBounds.southwest);
 mPolylineOptions.add(latLngBounds.northeast);

 mMap.addPolyline(mPolylineOptions);
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .position(latLngBounds.southwest));
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .position(latLngBounds.northeast));
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .position(latLngBounds.getCenter()));
```

[image]

`

```
private LatLngBounds getPolygonCenterPoint(GoogleMap mMap, List 
     < LatLng > polygonPointsList) {
      LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
      for (int i = 0; i < polygonPointsList.size(); i++) {
       builder.include(polygonPointsList.get(i));
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(polygonPointsList.get(i)));
      }
      LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
      return bounds;
     }
```

`

Comment: can you add some actual values for your coordinates, at present your pointers don't appear to be on either of the bbox corners (both of which could well be outside the polygon) - In your picture I would expect SW to be Adelaide and NE to be level with Brisbane (horizontally) and Newcastle (vertically).

Comment: For one - it's much easier to understand if the image is north aligned (which it's not) - second it seems you don't  understand what the lat lng bounds is - it is the minimum bounding rectangle containing every point which if you view it north-aligned can see the bottom point is aligned with Melbourne (southern most) and the top point is aligned with brisbayne (northern-most).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bounding box using the points of: Brisbane, Sydney, Melbourne & 
Adelaide *on a north-up map*.  As you can see the NE, SW corner points are consistent with the end points of your green line.  There is only one case where a bounding box would not be outside the contained polygon: when the polygon is a rectangle oriented along longitudinal lines and therefore coincident with the bounding box.

I'd suggest restating what your objective is - use a picture if it helps.

To prevent the green line from exceeding the polygon bounds, you'd have to compute the intersect points of the green line with each edge encountered - which becomes challenging for an arbitrary case.

[image]

For the arbitrary case (pictured below) what I suspect you're after is the intersecting portion of the NE-SW diagonal such as the green line (solid, no dashes).

Since you have the center point, Z, and the corner points NE,SW, you can compute the heading from Z-NE and Z-SW using `SphericalUtil.computeHeading`.  (Hne, Hsw).

Finding the intersecting points of the edges and the diagonal is best solved by first converting the lines to cartesian plane - compute the intersection - and convert back to WGS84 ellipsoid (with error).
[image]

Graphics courtesy online bounding box tool: https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/.

Comment: thanks for your effort but I didn't understand this (Finding the intersecting points of the edges and the diagonal is best solved by first converting the lines to the cartesian plane - compute the intersection - and convert back to the WGS84 ellipsoid)

Comment: Finding the intersection points on a sphere is much more difficult than a plane.  To convert to plane assume Z is the origin and compute the x/y positions of all points discussed (A,B,C,D,NE,SW).  Then use an approach such as this: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/approximate-points-of-intersection-of-two-line-segments.  Then convert x/y back to lat-long. Use SphericalUtil and PolyUtil (map utils) to assist in calculations.